# How to concatenate a string to the rule in scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from thirdapp.items import ThirdappItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/search?q=news',
        'http://www.example.com/search?q=movies',
        ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow('?q=news',), restrict_xpaths('ul[@class="paginator"]',)), callback='parse_item', allow=True),

        )
```

for example suppose that the restrict xpaths which in the rules should return something like this :

```
`bWFya2V0PT1nZW5lcmFsfHxzdD09MjB8fHN0cz09eyIxMCI6IlJlZ2lvbiIsIjIwIjoiTWlkZGxlIEVhc3QifQ%3D%3D`
```

i need to concatenate this with:

```
 https://www.catalogs.ssg.asia/toyota/?fromchanged=true&lang=en&l=
```

to be able to request the full url which is a concatenation of both:
desired url:

```
https://www.catalogs.ssg.asia/toyota/?fromchanged=true&lang=en&l=bWFya2V0PT1nZW5lcmFsfHxzdD09MjB8fHN0cz09eyIxMCI6IlJlZ2lvbiIsIjIwIjoiTWlkZGxlIEVhc3QifQ%3D%3D
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `link_extractor`, it will return the absolute URL, this is source code:

```
def _extract_links(self, selector, response_url, response_encoding, base_url):
    links = []
    # hacky way to get the underlying lxml parsed document
    for el, attr, attr_val in self._iter_links(selector.root):
        # pseudo lxml.html.HtmlElement.make_links_absolute(base_url)
        try:
            attr_val = urljoin(base_url, attr_val)
        except ValueError:
            continue # skipping bogus links
        else:
            url = self.process_attr(attr_val)
            if url is None:
                continue
        url = to_native_str(url, encoding=response_encoding)
        # to fix relative links after process_value
        url = urljoin(response_url, url)
        link = Link(url, _collect_string_content(el) or u'',
                    nofollow=rel_has_nofollow(el.get('rel')))
        links.append(link)
    return self._deduplicate_if_needed(links)
```

This part will get the absolute URL:

```
        # to fix relative links after process_value
        url = urljoin(response_url, url)
```

and the `base url` is from `response`:

```
base_url = get_base_url(response)
```

so, when you use `link_extractor`, you do not need to warry about the relative URL, `Scrapy` will convert it for you.